# How to disable ReSharper but keep dotTrace and dotMemory available in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio, reshape

I want to run dotTrace and dotMemory from Visual Studio 2022. I do not want ReSharper in any form or shape. Is there a way to achieve this?

*Please note - this question is about how to start dotTrace/Memory from VS with Resharper disable (or not installed altogether)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're asking here.  You clearly CAN install just dotTrace and dotMemory without ReSharper.  Just select them on the JetBrains install screen and don't select ReSharper:

[image]

I've just done this and they work and there's no ReSharper.

There are some references to 'ReSharper' in Visual Studio though: the licence screens for dotTrace and dotMemory mention it, and the menu is called ReSharper.

Further there are apparently some ReSharper options to override Visual Studio in the Extensions/Resharper/Options screen, although they aren't actually overriding Visual Studio as far as I can see.

For example 'Disable Visual Studio Inline Hints' is checked, but if you enable them in Visual Studio they still work.  That just looks like bad JetBrains programming to me, and can probably just be ignored.

Do you have an issue beyond all that?

Comment: If you want to run dottrace from VS you **have to** install resharper and keep it **on**.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true: if I install as above dotTrace is working fine (admittedly I've only tested in a simple C# console app).

Comment: To confirm I'm not missing something I just created a WPF application with event handling and used dotTrace on it, without ReSharper installed.  Again it worked fine.  We're going to need more information to help you here I think.

Comment: "and used dotTrace on it" - how did you do it from **inside Visual Studio** ? the question is not whether you can or cannot use dottrace. but how to do it in VS.. I think it is pretty clear in the question. ill add more explicit details

Comment: I used the menu option Extensions/ReSharper/Profile/Run Startup Configuration Performance Profiling and then just accepted the defaults on the next screen and clicked Start.  I don't have full ReSharper installed, and it worked.  We're definitely at cross-purposes here!

Comment: your experience is very different from mine. i couldnt manage to get "extension -> resharper" menu without installing resharper. i have to try again.. ill let you know